# Invoke Checkbox CheckedChanged event inside Calendar control

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

Currently I am working on a Asp.Net app. It has a Asp.Net Calendar control and OnDayRender() method I am dynamically adding Checkbox control inside it. I am attaching CheckedChanged event handler too. But whenever I am clicking on checkbox it is not invoking the server side CheckedChanged() method. Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

**Asp.Net code:**

```
     <div>  
         <asp:Calendar  
            ID="Calendar1"   
            runat="server"  
            NextPrevFormat="FullMonth"  
            ForeColor="WhiteSmoke"  
            SelectionMode="Day"  
            DayNameFormat="Full"  
            Font-Names="Book Antiqua"  
            Font-Size="Medium"  
            OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender">  
        </asp:Calendar>  
    </div>
```

**Server side:**

```
    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)  
    {  
            CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox();  
            checkBox1.AutoPostBack = true;  
            checkBox1.Width = 25;  
            checkBox1.Enabled = false;  
            checkBox1.CheckedChanged = checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
            e.Cell.Controls.AddAt(1, checkBox1);  
            e.Cell.Font.Size = FontUnit.XLarge;  
    }  


    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do some operation...
    }
```

Comment: Could you stop copy/paste content from wikipedia to create a tag-wiki? This is not what they are designed for. And by the way, before creating a tag-wiki for a new tag, check if it doesn't exists before (like [tag:compass] vs [tag:compass-css]).

Comment: @j0k Thanks for your valuable comment. i would definitely follow this guideline. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The Calendar’s `DayRender` event is exactly what is says it is - it’s an event fired during the render process, just before the cell for the given day is rendered.  Because this event is fired **so late in the page life cycle**, you cannot add controls that fire events.

From the [Calendar documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender.aspx):

*"Because the DayRender event is raised while the Calendar control is being rendered, you cannot add a control that can also raise an event, such as CheckBox. You can only add static controls, such as
LiteralControl, Label, Image, and HyperLink."*

Workaround [here](http://tinyurl.com/q76nssa).